# I want to connect angular frontend and spring boot backend using post method

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, post, httprequest

I want to connect angular frontend and springboot backend using post method.After i want to return the varibles after submitting angular form and return the values.get data from frontend show in the back end.

**Angular service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {UserDetails} from "./UserDetails";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserDetailsService {

  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/users";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(userDetails: UserDetails ): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl, userDetails);
}
}
```

**Springboot userController**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo.model.User;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")
@RestController
public class userController {
    static Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(userController.class);


    @PostMapping("users")
    public void getUsers(User user){
        String title = user.getTitle();
        logger.info("mess"+title);
    }
}
```

**spring boot user**

```
package com.example.demo.model;
public class User {
    private String title;
    public User(String title) {
        this.title = title;
     
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question? you're almost there, just need to call your api endpoint on angular and pass in the user object via json, make sure that your front end object has the same attributes as your java User object for easier sync between them. I would also recommend having your @PostMapping method return the string rather than having it set as void